Can I issue a single "session token" instead of access/refresh tokens?
The scenario: on-premise "web" application that needs authentication and authorization; there is no external authorization server (in OAuth terms) to rely on. So we have to build that into the application -- in OAuth terms, the authorization server and the resource server become the same.
The application has REST endpoints and clients should be able to access them without using a (cookie-based) web session, but with an "Authorization" HTTP header. OAuth would solve this, but I want to understand if, in my scenario, I could use a single "session token" instead of OAuth's access token/refresh token pair, and in particular the pros/cons of either solution.
The session token would take the role of both the AT and RT, that is, it can be used to authorize an action on resource AND to extend its time-to-live / obtain a new token. In this way, that session token would be somewhat similar to a classic session cookie. I imagine that its security properties are similar to that of session cookies, because only the transport mechanism ("Authorization" header instead of "Cookie" header) is different, together with what is implied by that: Javascript has to have access to the session token, and unlike a cookie it doesn't get sent with every request automatically.
Constraints:

It must be possible to revoke access by external means, so that session token cannot be self-contained (in the sense a JWT is), but must be checked against a database for every access. Server-side caching can mitigate performance problems, and the number of users is limited anyway, so this is not expected to be a problem.
Clients do NOT need an identity token in addition to the session token or AT/RT pair.

Are there any pros/cons I am missing?
Possibly related but assumes different constraints: Why Does OAuth v2 Have Both Access and Refresh Tokens?

I would aim to stay within the OAuth framework and follow its best practices, which have been vetted by many experts. You should not need to invent your own type of token.
ACCESS TOKENS
In OAuth terms, your session token is a long lived access token, for a client that is not configured to use a refresh token.
Pros:

Slightly simpler code

Cons:

The impact of exploits is increased - if an access token leaks somehow, it can be replayed by a malicious party for a much longer time

Personally, I would always combine access tokens with refresh tokens. Eg use an access token with a 15 minute lifetime and a refresh token with a 4 hour lifetime.
When possible the refresh token is protected by a client credential. Though a browser based client cannot supply one and has its own best practices instead (see below).
OPAQUE TOKENS
Access tokens and refresh tokens can be issued in an opaque format, similar to a UUID. When a client sends an opaque access token in API requests, the API (or an API gateway) introspects the opaque token to get the underlying token details. To improve performance, introspection results are often cached for a short time.
Pros:

Clients cannot read sensitive access token data intended only for APIs
You can revoke access immediately

Cons:

Requires extra remote calls

I would always aim to use opaque tokens as a confidentiality best practice.
AUTHORIZATION SERVER
An authorization server (from RFC 6749) can do the token issuing and storage for you. I would upgrade to one at some point. This suggests that you might separate your resource server and authorization server into 2 separate components to allow for this in future.
Pros:

Provides lots of security features out-of-the-box

Cons:

Another component to manage

You can use an on-premise authorization server, but I would aim to avoid a hosting design that needs to deploy APIs and all of their supporting components to customers. Ideally, aim for them to only need to run the browser based app.
TOKENS v COOKIES
A current best practice is to keep tokens out of the browser to protect against malicious JavaScript. For example, use an API gateway to provide multiple routes to your API, one that requires HttpOnly cookies and another that requires tokens.
Pros:

HttpOnly cookies limit the impact of XSS exploits

Cons:

Requires more backend work to issue cookies

Ideally, you could encrypt opaque tokens into HttpOnly cookies to keep tokens out of the browser. Since the browser cannot usually send a credential to protect the refresh token, you get this behavior:

API requests use a cookie to transport a short-lived access token to APIs
Token refresh requests just rewrite cookies containing the long lived refresh token

This does not solve all browser threats perfectly, eg it does not prevent an XSS attack using session riding to misuse cookies. But it mitigates token interception and exfiltration threats in line with the best practices doc that I link to above.
ID TOKEN
The ID token indicates that you use OpenID Connect. Benefits are not always major but worth having. Backend clients typically validate the ID token before issuing HttpOnly cookies.
Pros:

Improves client security a little
You get a token the client can read, with details of how and when the user authenticated
You get a userinfo endpoint to which the client can send its access token
You use extra parameters to control how authentication works

SUMMARY
In the longer term you might do multiple of these. If you are not using an authorization server, at least simulate its behaviors and consider implementing the first two items:

Use short lived access tokens and refresh tokens, in an opaque format
Use HttpOnly cookies in the browser
Use an authorization server
Use ID tokens


"Even if your app is on-premise and not exposed to the internet, you never know how things will change in future." -- Just to clear this up, the "on premise" was NOT meant to justify lax security, but as a reason why we cannot use "some" authorization server that is already present on the internet.

"if an access token leaks somehow, it can be replayed by a malicious party for a much longer time" -- the same is true for a refresh token.

"This suggests that you might separate your resource server and authorization server into 2 separate components to allow for this in future...Another component to manage
" -- This would add maintenance overhead for our users (not ourselves), which is precisely why we intend to keep the authorization server and resource server together.

"The ID token indicates that you use OpenID Connect" -- Sorry if I worded that in a confusing way. We are NOT using ID tokens or OpenID Connect. The clients only need an AT to make API calls. Any information about the user's identity is taken from the API, not from the tokens.

I made a couple of updates. I say how cookies and refresh are managed in the browser (XSS is the main concern there). It feels like you may be deploying your resource server to customer sites. That can get in the way of evolving your security in your preferred ways, since these days APIs use multiple security components.

Unfortunately, deploying the resource+authorization server on-premise at the customer is part of the core design of the application. For example, some customers don't allow direct internet connections from there for security reasons. If we could host this ourselves, I would have aimed for  a separate authorization server and plain OAuth2 from the beginning. I should have made that clearer in the question.
